# Combo Box implementation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am in the process of developing a cross-platform app for a Supplier Management System. My requirement is to say; when the user adds a new supplier name or product name, for the Input Text field to have a drop down list that will sort and short-list the entries as they type in the characters.

This functionality is available in a ComboBox (in C#), JComboBox (in Java) , Combobox (in Python with tkinter), and even the primitive Visual Basic 5, some 20 years ago.

Which widget or component can I use in Flutter for the same purpose?

I come across a third party package named dropdownfield at: https://pub.dev/packages/dropdownfield
but this package is now outdated and when upgraded to the null-safe version, it does not work with the example code given, and I simply don't have the knowledge yet to tweak around the dart file in the package or sample code, to make it usable.

Is there any other widget to accomplish this task (of an Input Text Box combined with a Dropdown list) in Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this solution that I settled for, for the benefit of whoever who reads this post, having a similar requirement.

A solution lies with flutter_typeahead widget, found here:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead

This widget could be used instead of RawAutocomplete or Autocomplete widgets.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

There is `DropDownButtonFormField` Widget. It is like a regular `TextField` with a dropdown menu embedded in it, and you can customize as if a TextField with `decoration` property.

Here is a sample code I am working on nowadays:
The `items` property should be a list of `DropDownMenuItem`

```
Widget _citiesDropDownMenu() {
return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 12, 10),
  child: DropdownButtonFormField(
    itemHeight: null,
    items: _cities(),
    onChanged: (value) {
      _selectedCity = value as String;
      setState(() {});
    },
    value: _selectedCity,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 12),
      helperText: 'Cities',
      fillColor: Colors.grey,
      filled: true,
      prefixIcon: Icon(
        Icons.city,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 60),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

items:

```
  List<DropdownMenuItem<Object>> _cities() {
return _citiesToDisplay
    .map((city) => DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(city), value: city))
    .toList();
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your response Suat but, DropdownButtonFormField cannot serve the purpose of the classic ComboBox functionality and it is not meant to do so. It does not give any provision at all for the user to type in like that of a regular TextField either.